# How to make the background of the first row of the table different color from the table?

Tags: html, css

I have a table and I want to make the first row different background color for instance blue. I use table tr:first-child but it doesn't work. Can you help me? Thanks.

```html
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet.

```css
table tr:first-child td {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tr:first-of-type`. check updated snippet below.

```css
table tr:first-of-type td {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
table tr:first-child {
    background: blue;
}
```

or you can add class to your first `tr`

```
.bg-blue {
   background:blue;
 }

<table>
  <tr class="bg-blue">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying the `first-child` is not working, I suggest you check it's parent property if it has any property which is overriding your `first-child` property. Basically, it should work that way. Also, I would like to know which browser actually you are seeing the issue.
Try this:

```css
table tr:first-child {
    background:blue;
   color:white;
   
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can add a comment with your issue if still it is not resolved with the solution.